# Как получить значение из SimpleType в SOAPClient?

Tags: php, xml, soap, xsd

Всем доброго. Сразу к делу.

Есть WSDL документ. В нем есть следующее:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="CurrencyTypeEnum">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
       <xsd:enumeration value="1" description="Рубли"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="2" description="Доллары"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

При выполнении `print_r($client->__getTypes())` я получаю должным образом

```
Array
(
    [0] => int CurrencyTypeEnum
}
```

**Вопрос:** как мне получить слово «Рубли» из всего этого массива средствами расширения SOAP в PHP?

*Облазил весь русскоязычный и англоязычный интернет. Такое ощущение что у меня недопонимание этой технологии SOAP.* Спасибо заранее.